# Elasticsearch query on top of aggregation that fetches the last event of each session

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an Elasticsearch index where each document corresponds to an event. Each event has its own id (used as the document id) and a session id. Multiple events can have the same session id.

**Question 1:** In some use cases I want to perform searches only on top of the last event of each session. This means that I first need to perform an aggregation that groups events by session id and then fetches the most recent one from each bucket. Only then, I query the result of the aggregation.

Note that the approach described in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html is the opposite from what I need, since the aggregation is performed on top of the result of the query.

**Question 2:** Is it possible to hide this logic from a Kibana user, i.e. almost like creating a view on Elasticsearch?

Restriction: I cannot modify the way the documents are modeled.

Comment: I don't think so it's possible just like that, out-of-the-box. But how about creating a second index where, periodically, you run a script of some sort that puts the documents resulting from that aggregation? And in Kibana, when you need this sort of data, you query this secondary, aggregated data index. Something based on this idea: https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/2015/sf/building-entity-centric-indexes

Comment: @AndreiStefan I know that this breaks the restriction that I mentioned. I'm thinking of having a field named "is_latest". When a new event for the session arrives, I update this field for the current event to be false, and add the new event with "is_latest" = true. Is it possible to do this in a single operation?

Comment: ES doesn't magically know which is the previous latest event, so somehow you'd have to get a hold of that document and update it. If you have the event it, theoretically you could do it in a single operation (a bulk with two operations in it), but the question remains "how do you get a hold of the previous latest event?"